# How to modify single widget in child theme?

Tags: widgets, actions

I'm trying to modify a widget title in a child theme from `H2` to `H1`. I copied the sidebar function from the parent theme's `functions.php` file to the child theme's `function.php` file according to the instructions in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24032515/functions-php-wordpress). This is the code I placed in my child theme's `functions.php` file:

```
remove_action('widgets_init', 'codilight_lite_widgets_init');

//Register your own hook.
add_action('widgets_init', 'my_widgets_init');

function my_widgets_init() {
register_sidebar( array(
    'name'          => esc_html__( 'Default Sidebar', 'codilight-lite' ),
    'id'            => 'sidebar-1',
    'description'   => '',
    'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget'  => '</aside>',
    'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widget-title"><span>',
    'after_title'   => '</span></h2>',
) );

// Homepage Template
register_sidebar( array(
    'name'          => esc_html__( 'Home 1', 'codilight-lite' ),
    'id'            => 'home-1',
    'description'   => '',
    'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="home-widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget'  => '</aside>',
    'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widget-title"><span>',
    'after_title'   => '</span></h2>',
) );
register_sidebar( array(
    'name'          => esc_html__( 'Home 2', 'codilight-lite' ),
    'id'            => 'home-2',
    'description'   => '',
    'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="home-widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget'  => '</aside>',
    'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widget-title"><span>',
    'after_title'   => '</span></h2>',
) );
register_sidebar( array(
    'name'          => esc_html__( 'Home 3', 'codilight-lite' ),
    'id'            => 'home-3',
    'description'   => '',
    'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="home-widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget'  => '</aside>',
    'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widget-title"><span>',
    'after_title'   => '</span></h2>',
) );
register_sidebar( array(
    'name'          => esc_html__( 'Home 4', 'codilight-lite' ),
    'id'            => 'home-4',
    'description'   => '',
    'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="home-widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget'  => '</aside>',
    'before_title'  => '<h1 class="widget-title"><span>',
    'after_title'   => '</span></h1>',
) );

}
```

The widget I'm trying to modify is the last one in the list, i.e, the `Home 4` widget. This code is not producing any errors, it's just not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I've found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22995302/overriding-parent-theme-functions-in-wordpress).
Here's the working version of the code I'm using in my child theme's `functions.php` file.

```
function my_widgets_init() {
register_sidebar( array(
    'name'          => esc_html__( 'Default Sidebar', 'codilight-lite' ),
    'id'            => 'sidebar-1',
    'description'   => '',
    'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget'  => '</aside>',
    'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widget-title"><span>',
    'after_title'   => '</span></h2>',
) );

// Homepage Template
register_sidebar( array(
    'name'          => esc_html__( 'Home 1', 'codilight-lite' ),
    'id'            => 'home-1',
    'description'   => '',
    'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="home-widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget'  => '</aside>',
    'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widget-title"><span>',
    'after_title'   => '</span></h2>',
) );
register_sidebar( array(
    'name'          => esc_html__( 'Home 2', 'codilight-lite' ),
    'id'            => 'home-2',
    'description'   => '',
    'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="home-widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget'  => '</aside>',
    'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widget-title"><span>',
    'after_title'   => '</span></h2>',
) );
register_sidebar( array(
    'name'          => esc_html__( 'Home 3', 'codilight-lite' ),
    'id'            => 'home-3',
    'description'   => '',
    'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="home-widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget'  => '</aside>',
    'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widget-title"><span>',
    'after_title'   => '</span></h2>',
) );
register_sidebar( array(
    'name'          => esc_html__( 'Home 4', 'codilight-lite' ),
    'id'            => 'home-4',
    'description'   => '',
    'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="home-widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget'  => '</aside>',
    'before_title'  => '<h1 class="widget-title"><span>',
    'after_title'   => '</span></h1>',
) );

}

add_action('after_setup_theme','remove_parent_widgets');

function remove_parent_widgets() {
remove_action( 'widgets_init', 'codilight_lite_widgets_init' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'my_widgets_init' );
```

Comment: Glad you solved your own answer, be sure to click the checkmark next to your answer to indicate that this question has been solved.